# How to create DSL.rowField() from RowN?

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I am currently playing around with JOOQs `DSL.arrayAgg(..)` and want to query all `PROJECTS` with each queried `PROJECT` row having a nested row of its `PROJECTMEMBERUSERS`. I have to join a `USER` for each `PROJECTMEMBERUSER`. The `USER` should be part of the same nested row as the `PROJECTMEMBERUSER`.

Below is the query as i want it to be:

```
db.select(
      PROJECTS.asterisk(),
      DSL.arrayAggDistinct(DSL.rowField(row(*PROJECTMEMBERUSERS.fields() + USERS.fields()))).`as`("memberusers")
)
      .from(
          PROJECTS
              .join(PROJECTMEMBERUSERS).on(PROJECTS.ID.eq(PROJECTMEMBERUSERS.PROJECTID))
              .join(USERS).on(USERS.ID.eq(PROJECTMEMBERUSERS.USERID))
      )
      .groupBy(PROJECTS.ID)
```

However `DSL.rowField(row(*PROJECTMEMBERUSERS.fields() + USERS.fields()))` is not possible because `DSL.rowField(..)` does not accept `RowN` (the return type of `row(..)` in this case. I could of course create the row by hand, but there must be a better option to create a row out of more than one table.

**Is there any better solution than creating the row of two tables by hand?**

Comment: In SQL, you could create `ROW(projectmemberusers, users)` and have a doubly nested record in your aggregation. But given that `DSL.rowField()` is already experimental in jOOQ, I suspect that might not really work out of the box with jOOQ.